# Mi Band 2 past data

Tags: android, python, bluetooth, gatt, xiaomi

I'm writing my thesis on how to obtain data from different fitness bands.
At the moment I'm doing some research on the Mi Band 2 using bluetooth connection with my PC, unfortunately BLE is a new field for me.

By looking at projects like [Gadgetbridge](https://github.com/Freeyourgadget/Gadgetbridge) or [miband2-python-test](https://github.com/vshymanskyy/miband2-python-test) I try to understand the protocol. I get how the authentication works and how to extract data like battery or time information. However, I don't understand the protocol to obtain past data, like the minutely steps from two days ago until now.

I would be pleased if someone could help me by giving a tip or explaining the steps of the protocol. Thanks in advance!

That's my code for now, as far as I understood the protocol:

```
UUID_CHAR_ACTIVITY_DATA = "00000005-0000-3512-2118-0009af100700"
UUID_CHAR_FETCH = "00000004-0000-3512-2118-0009af100700"
CCCD_UUID = 0x2902

class MiBand2(Peripheral):
    [...]
    self.char_activity_data =   self.getCharacteristics(uuid=UUID_CHAR_ACTIVITY_DATA)[0]
    self.char_fetch = self.getCharacteristics(uuid=UUID_CHAR_FETCH)[0]
    self.cccd_fetch = self.char_fetch.getDescriptors(forUUID=CCCD_UUID)[0]
    def fetch_activity_data(self):
        # \x01\x01  key?
        # \xe2\x07  2018 year
        # \x05      month
        # \x03      year
        # \x11      hour
        # \x2f      minute
        # \x00\x08 timezone
        value = b'\x01\x01\xe2\x07\x05\x03\x11\x2f\x00\x08'     
        self.cccd_fetch.write(b'\x01\x00', False)
        self.char_fetch.write(value_from_wireshark, False)
        for i in range(30):
            self.waitForNotifications(1.0)


class AuthenticationDelegate(DefaultDelegate):
    [...]
    def handleNotification(self, hnd, data):
        [...]
        if hnd == self.device.char_fetch.getHandle():
            if data[:3] == b'\x10\x01\x01':
                self.device.char_activity_data.write(b'\x01\x00', False)
                # After \x02 I receive \x10\x02\x01 instead of fitness data as I thought
                self.device.char_fetch.write(b'\x02', False)
```

Comment: there are several steps for authentication including sending your keys and encrypt it. check this out [http://www.shewhocodes.ml/2018/05/cordova-ble-how-to-connect-to-mi-band-2]

Answer (score 0):

It is need to analyze btsnoop_hci.log

On every 30 minute the device send a notification value 0x0e from 00000010-0000-3512-2118-0009af100700. Then you must start to take your past data. Firstly you need to enable notification descriptors for UUID_CHAR_ACTIVITY_DATA and so called UUID_CHAR_FETCH. Then you need to get count of packages from your last successful getting of data. So you send a value 0x0101+datatime+tz to UUID_CHAR_FETCH. The device response to you with value of 0x100101+packages_count+1st_package_datetimetz if no gaps the 1st_package_datetimetz is that you send previously. Now you need to start transfer past data, just send one byte value 0x02 to UUID_CHAR_FETCH and device will send notifications from UUID_CHAR_ACTIVITY_DATA. Every activity data notification value has a queue number in first byte and maximum 4 packages of data in remain bytes. Every single package of past data consists of 4 bytes and has this format: activity_type,intensity,steps,heart_rate. The device stores data for every minute. So usualy on every 0x0e event you will get 30 packages in 8 notification message values by 4 packages most of time. After the last notification got the device will send notification of success 0x100201 from UUID_CHAR_FETCH. I don't know why but it need to be done the last 3-rd step: send a single byte 0x03 to UUID_CHAR_FETCH then get success response 0x100301. This actualy all what you need but Mi Fit does bouble check for a new data packages, then gets zero count and then does last 3-rd step. Now it need to set notification descriptors off with value 0x0000. After all this your success synchronize datatime will be grater for count of past data packets you got * 60 seconds.

If you have response packages count = 0 after 0x0101 command the device will obviously send to you nothing after command 0x02 and then send success 0x100201 :)

I don't know what for 0x0102+datatimetz is. It always response packages count = 0 in my btsnoop_hci.logs.

I think it is not necessary to synchronize by 0x0e event.

https://gist.github.com/Roxxor91/0d3ff17153270e447d01e7afd0c54e0f